# I need to count and group records held on SQL Server 2003 by a combined Year Week String

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-concatenation

I have been asked to graph data held in SQL Server. This I can do with the tools I have available.

However I have been asked to count the number of records in the database, grouping them based on a combination of last two digits of the Year, and the week number

For example the first week of 2011 would be 1101
    example the fifteenth week of 2010 would be 1015

(note need week as 2 char) so index who alphabetically

I have tried various combinations such as

```
select CASE WHEN DATENAME(ww,j.requestedat) <= 9
            THEN (CAST('0' AS VARCHAR(1)) + CAST(DATENAME(ww,j.requestedat) AS VARCHAR(1)))
            ELSE CAST(DATENAME(ww,j.requestedat) AS VARCHAR(2))
         END AS WeekNumber
         , right(DateName(yy, j.requestedat),2) + WeekNumber as YYWW
from
    facts_reactive.dbo.jobs j 
order by j.requestedat
```

but all have failed.

Any help/guidance gratefully accepted.

Rob

Comment: There is no SQL Server 2003 - options are SQL 2000, 2005 or 2008. Do you mean you want code which is compliant to the ANSI SQL 2003 standad?

Comment: Informed by the administrator of the database that that was the version of SQL Server; it has been running on this site since 2004, so I think I am safe in assuming SQL Server 2000, and the code needs to be Transact-SQL.  Thanks for helping to clear up what could have caused confusion to other reviewers.

Comment: Looking at your comments on the answers this question has been answered satisfactorily. Could you accept one of the answers then please?

Answer (score 1):

try this one :

```
select
    right(DateName(yy, wn.requestedat),2) + wn.WeekNumber as YYWW
from
    (
        select CASE WHEN DATENAME(ww,j.requestedat) <= 9
                THEN (CAST('0' AS VARCHAR(1)) + CAST(DATENAME(ww,j.requestedat) AS VARCHAR(1)))
                ELSE CAST(DATENAME(ww,j.requestedat) AS VARCHAR(2))
             END as WeekNumber, j.requestedat
        from
            facts_reactive.dbo.jobs j      
    ) AS wn
order by wn.requestedat
```

Comment: Utterly fantastic, and shows me how to use a subselect also.  Many thanks Xavinou.  I feel humbled by this forums generousity.

Comment: Looking at your solution which is my greatest hope to group the end result YYWW, I now see that you have not created a subselect (my lack of knowledge) but a derived table .. thanks for leading me to a new and fruitful area of knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT RIGHT(YEAR(j.requestedat),2) + RIGHT('00'+CAST(DATEPART(ww,j.requestedat) AS VARCHAR(2)),2) YYWW
FROM facts_reactive.dbo.jobs j  
ORDER BY j.requestedat
```

Comment: Wow beautifully simple, and giving a string as the result.  Many thanks Lamak.   I am stunned by everyones brilliance and kindness.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  YYWW = RIGHT(YEAR(j.requestedat) * 100 + DATEPART(ww, j.requestedat), 4)
FROM facts_reactive.dbo.jobs j
ORDER BY j.requestedat
```

Comment: Very clever way of doing it as an actual integer; something I should of thought of doing, but your solution is elegantly simple.  Many thanks Andriy.   Again, I feel humbled by this forums generousity.

Comment: @robert. The pleasure is all mine. :)